# Why did Wildfly lost deployments?

Tags: wildfly

I am working with Wildfly since several weeks. I do a lot of autodeplyoment and hotdeployment during development.
The strange problem I am faced with is, that sometimes (e.g. after a restart) all deployments are gone. It seems the JDBC driver which I deploy via WildFly Web Console is lost and than all other deployed units are also lost.
To solve this problem it seems the only solution is:

- top wildfly
- remove all artefacts from '/standalone/deployments'
- restart wildfly
- redeploy JDBC driver
- redeploy all applications

Did anybody know why this happens and how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: How are you starting WildFly?

Comment: Which version of WildFly are you using ? Could it be https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-64 ?

Comment: I am using Wildfly 8.2-final. I recognized the problem from the beginning (8.0). I do starting Wildfly from console with the ./standalone.sh script. I will check the issue WFCORE-64 and give asap my feedback

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same problem here..

Comment: I have started to work with Wildfly 9.0.1. It looks like the problem is gone.